# Issue with tooltip on Highcharts with multiple series added dynamically

Tags: highcharts

Hello I am currently facing a problem with the tooltip on my chart which adds data dynamically through the use of Series.SetData() function of highcharts.
The issue however is not related to the data which is added I think but with the tooltip everytime I mouse over a point in the graph.

To better understand I will post two screenshots with the issue:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image]

Whenever I mouse over a certain point in the graph the tooltip keeps changing and the values presented are the ones posted in the screenshots. If I drag the mouse away the tooltip that remains on the screen is the second one and I am no longer able to see the Y1 value.
I probably have some bad chart configuration so here is the code of my graph:

```
 $(function () {

    // Create the chart for node 1
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x',
            events: {
                load: requestDataNode1
            },
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Live Data'
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                count: 1,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '1M'
            }, {
                count: 5,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '5M'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            inputEnabled: false,
            selected: 0
        },
        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    //return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                    return this.value;
                }
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 2,
                color: 'silver'
            }]
        },
        legend:{    enabled: true},
        plotOptions: {
            series: {

                showInNavigator: true
            },
            spline: {
                turboThreshold: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                enableMouseTracking: true
            }

        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2,
            split: false
        },
        navigator: {

            series: {
                data: []
            }
        },
    });


});
```

I do not know why this happens , at first I thought it could be related with not having a value for a series for a specific date but then I checked my series as you can see in the screenshots and there is indeed a value for both series.

I thank in advance for your help.

Comment: I cannot find any incorrect configuration in the chart - unless you recreate the issue fully, I will not be able to say where the issue is. https://jsfiddle.net/2q5nkkbw/

Answer (score 0):

I somehow resolved this issue by adding the shared property in the tooltip property and setting to false, however now I only receive a single value.
Is it possible to keep seeing all values?